# convert oracle condition query to solrj query

Tags: java, solrj, solr4

I have to convert below oracle query to solr using java(solrj)

```
select xx as zz from table where condition
UNION
select nvl(xx yy) as zz from table where condition1
```

How this can do in solrj.